# How can i realize filter by two parameters in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Can I somehow do filter by name and description simultaneously?
I can realize filter by name or by description but don't understand how to do it simultaneously.

```
    render() {
        let filteredProducts = this.props.productList.filter(
            (value)=>{
                return value.description.indexOf(this.state.value) !== -1;
            }
        );
        return (
            <div className="product">
            <input type="text" name="find" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    {filteredProducts.map((value,index)=>{
                        return(
                            <div className="product__card" key={index}>
                                <div className="product__card-info">
                                    <h1>{value.name}</h1>
                                    <span>{value.price}</span>
                                </div>
                                <p>{value.description}</p>
                                <DeleteProduct 
                                    onDelete={this.props.onDelete}
                                    productId={value.id}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Array that I map and filter look like this

```
productList:[
    {
       name: "Test",
       description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis exercitationem perferendis debitis dolores neque hic nam eveniet aliquid sit, obcaecati unde accusantium dolorem adipisci expedita voluptas dolor laborum ex optio!",
       price: 100
    }
]
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: maybe just use them both? `value.description.indexOf || value.name.indexOf`... if you need to filter by a lot of fields it may make more sense to just stringify the object and do a comparison there

Comment: Yes but when i try to do this i have error.I don't know how do this right

Comment: instead of saying `I have error` describe what the issue is, or update the post to show whats failing. Error means nothing except "something" didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

(Note that the examples below don't define the behavior for when nothing is selected for name/description.)

[Updated to include changes based on John Ruddells comments. Good catch.]

Try this if you want to show the rows that match both the name *and* the description.

```
const filteredProducts = this.props.productList.filter(value => 
  value.description.indexOf(this.state.value) !== -1
  && value.name.indexOf(this.state.name) !== -1);
```

Or this if you want to show the rows that match the name *or* this description.

```
const filteredProducts = this.props.productList.filter(value => 
  value.description.indexOf(this.state.value) !== -1
  || value.name.indexOf(this.state.name) !== -1);
```

Comment: I think you want to use `||` here since either or matching should be returned

Comment: It's doesn't work.There no error but It's doesn't work

Comment: Thank you! I find error in my code with "name". Now it is all right.

Comment: How are you going about selecting the name / description to filter by? I see that you're putting the description in this.state.value. Are you by chance also putting the selected name in this.state.value? If so, that's the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use Array.prototype.find() with logical operators?

Like:

```
let filteredList = this.props.productList.find( n => n.name === this.state.x && n.description === this.state.y)
```

If this "this.state.value" indicate productList objects "price" then change n.description or n.name, like:

```
... n.price === this.state.value
```